# Flutter- Convert list to json and store in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, list, flutter, dart, encode

I am making an app for restaurant menu and I am stuck in the procedure of order. I am trying to store the the list of food items in MYSQL database when the button place order is pressed. I think I know the concept to store the list but could not do it. I am trying to loop through through the food items in the list and get name and quantity of all food items present in list, encode the list and use post request to store data.

The class is Place Order where I have done the order procedure.

```
import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:menu_app/Regular/regularItems.dart';
import 'cartListBloc.dart';
import 'dart:convert'; //to convert http response in json format
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cart({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  List<FoodItem> foodItems = new List<FoodItem>();
  var listUpdate = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CartListBloc bloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<CartListBloc>();

    return BlocProvider(
        blocs: [Bloc((i) => CartListBloc())],
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: bloc.listStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {
              if (!listUpdate) {
                foodItems = snapshot.data;
              }
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
                  title: Text('Food Cart'),
                  centerTitle: true,
                ),
                body: SafeArea(
                  child: CartBody(foodItems, updateList),
                ),
                bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(foodItems, updateList),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  void updateList(List<FoodItem> list) {
    setState(() {
      listUpdate = true;
      foodItems = list;
    });
  }
}

class BottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  // final List<FoodItem> foodItems;
  List<FoodItem> foodItems;
  Function updateList;
  BottomBar(this.foodItems, this.updateList);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, bottom: 15),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          totalAmount(foodItems),
          Divider(
            height: 5,
            color: Colors.brown,
          ),
          PlaceOrder(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container totalAmount(List<FoodItem> foodItems) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Total:",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
          ),
          Text(
            "\Rs ${returnTotalAmount(foodItems)}",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 25),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String returnTotalAmount(List<FoodItem> foodItems) {
    double totalAmount = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < foodItems.length; i++) {
      totalAmount = totalAmount + foodItems[i].price * foodItems[i].Quantity;
    }
    return totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
}

class CartBody extends StatelessWidget {
  CartBody(this.foodItems, this.updateList);
  final List<FoodItem> foodItems;
  Function updateList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Table(),
            //CustomBar(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: foodItems.length > 0 ? foodItemList() : noItemContainer(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container noItemContainer() {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Text(
      "No food item in the cart.",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black26,
        fontSize: 25,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        fontFamily: 'Rancho-Regular',
      ),
    )));
  }

  ListView foodItemList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: foodItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ItemContent(
            foodItem: foodItems[index],
            foodItems: foodItems,
            updateList: updateList,
            index: index);
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomQuantity extends StatefulWidget {
  final FoodItem foodItem;
  List<FoodItem> foodItems;
  Function updateList;
  int index;

  CustomQuantity(this.foodItem, this.foodItems, this.updateList, this.index);

  @override
  _CustomQuantityState createState() => _CustomQuantityState();
}

class _CustomQuantityState extends State<CustomQuantity> {
  final double _buttonWidth = 28;

  final CartListBloc bloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<CartListBloc>();
  removeFromList(FoodItem foodItems) {
    bloc.removeFromList(foodItems);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      width: 90,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: _buttonWidth,
            height: _buttonWidth,
            child: FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              onPressed: () {
                //  setState(() {});

                if (widget.foodItems[widget.index].Quantity > 1) {
                  widget.foodItems[widget.index].Quantity--;
                  print(widget.foodItems[widget.index].Quantity);
                  print(widget.foodItem.Quantity * widget.foodItem.price);
                } else {
                  removeFromList(widget.foodItems[widget.index]);
                  print('remove');
                }

                widget.updateList(widget.foodItems);
                //   return widget.cart.foodItems[widget.index].quantity;
              },
              child: Text(
                "-",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    color: Colors.brown),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            widget.foodItems[widget.index].Quantity.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.brown),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: _buttonWidth,
            height: _buttonWidth,
            child: FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              onPressed: () {
                // setState(() {

                //   print(widget.foodItem.quantity);
                //   print(widget.foodItem.quantity * widget.foodItem.price);
                // });
                widget.foodItems[widget.index].Quantity++;
                widget.updateList(widget.foodItems);
                //    return widget.cart.foodItems[widget.index].quantity;
              },
              child: Text(
                "+",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.brown),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemContent(
      {Key key,
      @required this.foodItem,
      this.foodItems,
      this.updateList,
      this.index})
      : super(key: key);

  final FoodItem foodItem;
  final List<FoodItem> foodItems;
  final int index;
  final Function updateList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var customQuantity = CustomQuantity(foodItem, foodItems, updateList, index);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              child: Image.asset(
                'system/public/foodItems/' + foodItem.image,
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                height: 50,
                width: 70,
              ),
            ),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 21,
                      fontFamily: 'Rancho-regular',
                      color: Colors.brown,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: foodItem.Name,
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
            CustomQuantity(foodItem, foodItems, updateList, index),
            Text("\Rs ${foodItem.price * customQuantity.foodItem.Quantity}",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontFamily: 'Rancho-regular',
                    fontSize: 21)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Table extends StatelessWidget {
  const Table({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tableController = TextEditingController(text: '    Table-1');
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(130, 0, 130, 0),
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: tableController,
          enabled: false,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.brown,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 22,
              fontFamily: 'Rancho-Regular'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlaceOrder extends StatefulWidget {
  static final url = 'http://192.168.254.2:8000/api/order/';
  const PlaceOrder({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlaceOrderState createState() => _PlaceOrderState();
}

class _PlaceOrderState extends State<PlaceOrder> {

 //converting list into an Json Array
  List encondeToJson(List<FoodItem> foodItems) {
    List jsonList = List();
    foodItems.map((item) => jsonList.add(item.toJson())).toList();
    return jsonList;
  }

  List<FoodItem> loopForOrder(List<FoodItem> foodItems) {
    for (int i = 0; i < foodItems.length; i++) {
      foodItems = [
        FoodItem(Name: foodItems[i].Name, Quantity: foodItems[i].Quantity)
      ];
    }
    print(foodItems.length);
    print('order completed');
    return encondeToJson(foodItems);
  }

  //var foodItems= [FoodItem(Name: 'Cheese Burger',Quantity: 3),FoodItem(Name: 'Lemon Mojito',Quantity: 1)];

  var tableController = TextEditingController(text: 'Table-1');

  bool visible = false;

  Future requestOrder() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      'http://192.168.254.2:8000/api/order/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'tableNo': tableController.text,
        'status': 0,
        'cart': loopForOrder,
      }),
    );
    print(loopForOrder);
    //print(loopForOrder.length);
    print('statuscode = ' + response.statusCode.toString());
    return loopForOrder;
  }

  Future<void> confirmation() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Order placement confirmation.',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Lobster-regular',
                fontSize: 18,
              )),

          content: Text('Do you wish to place order?',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lobster-regular', fontSize: 14)),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
                visible: visible,
                child: Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: requestOrder,
              child: Text('Yes',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontFamily: 'Lobster-regular',
                      fontSize: 20)),
            ),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('No',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontFamily: 'Lobster-regular',
                        fontSize: 20))),
          ],
          elevation: 24,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,

          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0))),
          //shape: CircleBorder(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 15, 0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.grey[400],
            elevation: 18,
            onPressed: confirmation,
            child: Text('Place Order',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.brown,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                  fontFamily: 'Rancho-Regular',
                )),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.brown, width: 2),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // Visibility(
        //     visible: visible,
        //     child: Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard know where is your code not working since you are pasting the whole code.
I am assuming this, but you have problems building the POST request?
I would create a Class and a Method toMap() for example :

```
class OrderRequest{
  String tableNo;
  int status;
  List<FoodItem> cart;
  OrderRequest({this.tableNo,this.status,this.cart});



Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['tableNo'] = tableNo;
    map['status'] = status;
    map['cart'] = cart;
    return map;
  }
}
```

Then, you can make request like this:

```
static Future<String> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
// todo - you should check the response.statusCode
String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
httpClient.close();
return reply;}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Actually I have problem in the class "Place Order" which is at the end of the whole code. I looked on to your solution but I am not clear fully, I am just a student and been engaged in a college project. Can you please tell me if the process I have been following in the class "Place Order" is wrong and if not what is the problem with it?